# Replacing moen moentrol shower trim

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower

I have two showers that are back to back, making accessing the valves extraordinarily difficult (no closet or access behind them). So, I don't really want to get into the business of replacing the valves - and I understand it's fairly complicated even if I did.

I'd like to replace the trim on all the spigots and handles with brushed nickel trim. The valves are Moentrol style valves by Moen. I see lots of options for Posi-Temp trim kits, but the only Moentrol trim kits are either $400 or chrome. This doesn't make sense to me... I can get a Moentrol chrome kit for $120. I can get a Posi-Temp brushed nickel kit for $120. Why are Moentrol brushed nickel kits $350?

I've seen that Danco makes brushed nickel replacement kits that work with Moentrol. However, I found that it was a really cheap product... it was plastic and it didn't sit flush on my shower.

Do I have any other options? I don't want to replace my valve, nor do I want to spend $350 when there are beautiful, high-quality trim kits available for $120.

Suggestions?

Comment: How big of a hole do you have to work with in your showers?  Often replacing out valve isn't a huge deal especially with your sharkbite varieties of compression connectors.

Comment: It's maybe a 4-inch diameter hole...

Comment: How big is your trim piece currently?

Comment: Maybe 7 or 8 inch diameter?

Comment: You can definitely install a valve with 7 inches... Basically your choices are open up wall a little more and install bigger trim piece or order whatever you can find that is compatible.  Whatever you need specifically will inevitably cost more.  It's a trim kit though, so another option is wait until you see one for a reasonable price.  Have you looked at the big sites for trim kits that are compatible?

Comment: John, I'm facing the exact same task as you, and came here looking for answers. Thanks for coming back and posting the info about the universal kit, I am going to look into it. I think I have some info about the changes in shower valve technology that I learned from the Moen site: they are driven by changes in code. New regulations since our houses were built include "pressure balance" to keep the water temperature constant if someone flushes a toilet, and a temperature control (PosiTemp) that limits the temperature of the water to 120 degrees, even if the water coming from the water heater is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.pfisterfaucets.com/Bath/Product/R90-TD2K.aspx

Found this puppy at Home Depot. It's a universal kit, like the Danco, but it's actually high quality. Did the job and looks great. Cost me $99.

Also, I was saying my valve was a "Moentrol" based on the Danco trim instructions. Turns out, it was actually not a moentrol. It's a "moen standard" which still pulls out to turn on/off, but operates on a different mechanism. Who knew? I have a hard time believing that shower valve technology has advanced so much in the last 25 years that Moen has had to develop 3 different valve types over that time. But who am I to say?

Answer (score 0):

Moentrol is the type of valve, the single knob that pulls out and pushes in for flow control and rotates right and left for temperature control. There were numerous trim styles offered with that valve type, so just saying "Moentrol" does not adequately describe your needs. Some of the old trim plates were marked with the word Moentrol, but many were not. If you contact www.lasco.net they will direct you to a dealer. They have a huge line of plated trim in all finishes (ask for the Simpatico line) at reasonable prices and of good quality.They call it Satin Nickel but it looks like brushed nickel. You might need to take your old trim to the dealer to ensure proper size/type, rather than risking an on-line purchase.